# R- multiplot con ggplot de barras

Tags: r

Soy muy nuevo en R y no entiendo qué me está fallando en el multiplot que quiero hacer.
Estoy trabajando con el dataset de kaggle - beers

```
p1 <- dataomitted %>% group_by(review_overall) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= review_overall, y=n))+
  geom_col()

p2 <- dataomitted %>% group_by(review_aroma) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= review_aroma, y=n))+
  geom_col()

p3 <- dataomitted %>% group_by(review_appearance) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= review_appearance, y=n))+
  geom_col()

p4 <- dataomitted %>% group_by(review_palate) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= review_palate, y=n))+
  geom_col()

p5 <- dataomitted %>% group_by(review_taste) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= review_taste, y=n))+
  geom_col()

p6 <- dataomitted %>% group_by(review_time) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= review_time, y=n))+
  geom_col()

ggplot2.multiplot (p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6, cols =3)
```

El error que me muestra es:

```
Error in ggplot2.multiplot(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, cols = 3) : 
  no se pudo encontrar la función "ggplot2.multiplot"
```

Al comienzo del documento he indicado  `if (!require('ggplot2')) install.packages('ggplot2'); library('ggplot2')` por lo que no entiendo qué función no es posible encontrar.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

El error es bastante claro: `R` no puede encontrar la función. El problema es que la función que estás tratando de usar no está en la librería `ggplot2`, sino en [easyGgplot2](https://github.com/kassambara/easyGgplot2). Si quieres usarla necesitas tener esa librería instalada y cargada.

Como esa librería no está en el repositorio oficial [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/) es necesario instalarla directamente desde el repositorio en github con la función `install_github`.

El siguiente código debería funcionar:

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("kassambara/easyGgplot2")
```

Como que la librería `easyGgplot` no está en CRAN algunas veces puede ser complicado instalarla. Aún con sus propios problemas, CRAN garantiza que las librerías cumplen con ciertos tests y no tienen conflictos de dependencias. Las librerías disponibles en GitHub no siempre. Quizás sea buena idea usar otra librería que hace más o menos lo mismo y sí está en CRAN. Por ejemplo, `patchwork`. La versión estable se instala con `install.packages(patchwork)`. En https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/ hay documentación suficiente para empezarla a usar.

Comment: He añadido lo que me indicas, me sale el error ```Loading required package: usethis
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘devtools’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'pkgload', details:
  call: loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]])
  error: namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.8 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.9 is required
Además: Warning message:
package ‘devtools’ was built under R version 4.0.3``` He añadido el package "rlang", pero el fallo sigue siendo el mismo

Comment: ¿Verificaste si la instalación de `devtools` se completó correctamente? Y con respecto a `rlang` ¿qué versión pudiste instalar? Te sugiero pegar el resultado de  `sessionInfo()` para ver qué paquetes tienes cargados y en que versiones.

Comment: ```rlang``` -> 0.4.8 / ```devtools``` -> 2.3.2

Comment: Por el error requieres `rlang >= 0.4.9`.  Puedes actualizarlo directamente con `install.packages`, hazlo en una sesión nueva de R. Asegúrate de obtener `Done` cuando termines de instalarlo. Si tienes algún error de instalación de `rlang` entonces seguirás teniendo la versión anterior. Opinión personal: usa un paquete que esté en CRAN, es más fácil y más seguro. En este caso el autor de `easyGgplot2` es alguien serio y que contribuye mucho con paquetes, pero no siempre lo puedes saber de antemano.